# Python 2.7 - Calculate quantiles per row

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, statistics, series

I have a pandas series like this:

```
0       1787
1       4789
2       1350
3       1476
4          0
5        747
6        307
7        147
8        221
9        -88
10      9374
11       264
12      1109
13       502
14       360
15       194
16      4073
17      2317
18      -221
20         0
21        16
22       106
29       105
30      4189
31       171
32        42
```

I want to create 4 one hot encoded variables that indicates which value per row is on which quartile, dividing the series into 4 quartiles. It would be something like this:

```
0       1787   Q1   Q2  Q3  Q4
1       4789   0    0   0   0
2       1350   0    0   0   1
3       1476   1    0   0   0
4          0   0    1   0   0 
5        747   0    0   1   0
6        307   1    0   1   0
7        147   0    1   0   1
```

I know the numbers do not exactly match, this is is just to give a visual example of the desired output.

I have tried this:

```
series.quantile[0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
```

But this only yells this four values:

```
0.25         67
0.50      442.5
0.75    1477.75
1.00      71188
```

I have also tried this:

```
series.apply(lambda x : series.quantile(x, 'lower'))
```

However this is giving the following error:

`ValueError: percentiles should all be in the interval [0, 1]. Try 17.87 instead`.

What's the best way to accomplisg my goal??

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code featuring [pandas.qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html) and [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) should do

```
quantiles = pd.qcut(series,
                    [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1],
                    labels=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'])
dummies = pd.get_dummies(quantiles)
pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
```

resuling in

```
    Series  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
0     1787   0   0   0   1
1     4789   0   0   0   1
2     1350   0   0   1   0
3     1476   0   0   0   1
4        0   1   0   0   0
5      747   0   0   1   0
6      307   0   0   1   0
7      147   0   1   0   0
8      221   0   1   0   0
9      -88   1   0   0   0
10    9374   0   0   0   1
11     264   0   1   0   0
12    1109   0   0   1   0
13     502   0   0   1   0
14     360   0   0   1   0
15     194   0   1   0   0
16    4073   0   0   0   1
17    2317   0   0   0   1
18    -221   1   0   0   0
20       0   1   0   0   0
21      16   1   0   0   0
22     106   0   1   0   0
29     105   1   0   0   0
30    4189   0   0   0   1
31     171   0   1   0   0
32      42   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: Hi @ayorgo. Thank you for your answer!! this works exactly as i wanted !! thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this.

1. Create a dataframe with the series

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Series': series})
```

2. Create a second df with the quantiles data (including 0)

```
quantiles = df['Series'].quantile([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]).to_frame('quantiles').reset_index(drop = True)
```

3. Create Q columns with this for loop.

```
for quant, Q in enumerate(['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']):
    quant = quant + 1
    df.loc[:,Q] = np.where((df.Series > quantiles.quantiles[quant-1]) & (df.Series <= quantiles.quantiles[quant]), 1, 0)
```

that should give you this:

```
Series  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
0   1787    0   0   0   1
1   4789    0   0   0   1
2   1350    0   0   1   0
3   1476    0   0   0   1
4   0   1   0   0   0
5   747 0   0   1   0
6   307 0   0   1   0
7   147 0   1   0   0
8   221 0   1   0   0
9   -88 1   0   0   0
10  9374    0   0   0   1
11  264 0   1   0   0
12  1109    0   0   1   0
13  502 0   0   1   0
14  360 0   0   1   0
15  194 0   1   0   0
16  4073    0   0   0   1
17  2317    0   0   0   1
18  -221    0   0   0   0
19  0   1   0   0   0
20  16  1   0   0   0
21  106 0   1   0   0
22  105 1   0   0   0
23  4189    0   0   0   1
24  171 0   1   0   0
25  42  1   0   0   0
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, thank you very much for your answer. However, there is a sintax error in this line: `quant = quant + 1 df.loc[:,Q] = np.where((df.Series > quantiles.quantiles[quant-1]) & (df.Series <= quantiles.quantiles[quant]), 1, 0)` and i can't manage to solve it since i don't really understand the structure of your comand

Comment: @Miguel2488 Can you post the error? Did you import pandas as pd and numpy as np? It might be that I called your series with capital 'S' (Series) and you have it as series? Usually, small changes cause big problems. Please let me know if you fix it.

Comment: @Miguel2488 The error comes from me using python 3 and you using python 2.7 (my bad). Change df.loc[:,Q] with df[Q]