# Flagging outliers

Tags: python-3.x, loops, outliers

I'm trying to : 
1- Define an outlier criteria ( up (hi) and low (lo) ). 
3- Compute every observation ( per column)
2- Flag the outliers

My dataset,h_median (pandas dataframe) has 30 columns and 4 rows, so I need a loop for it. 
I'm at the point of defining the criteria:

```
def remove_outlier(h_median,variables):
    q1 = h_median[variables].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = h_median[variables].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1 #Interquartile range
    fence_low  = q1-1.5*iqr
    fence_high = q3+1.5*iqr
    df_out = h_median.loc[(h_median[variables]> fence_low) & 
    (h_median[variables]< fence_high)]
    return df_out`
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692659/python-2-7-calculate-quantiles-per-row

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692659/python-2-7-calculate-quantiles-per-row
They were looking to id values in 4 different quantiles, but you can change that in the command to select the quantiles.